# How to beat last boss in regalia of men and monarchs?

Tags: regalia-of-men-and-monarchs

I am playing on normal mode, so I cannot skip battles, I finally managed to get to the end of the game but the last boss is brutal.

> 10k+ health and he gets 1k of shields per turn (at first one can take shields off by killing his soldiers). 
>  Apparently, there is a hack with Harieta to move the instadeath debuff to the boss, but I didn't pick her in diplomacy quests. The other suggestion to use Griffith as a punching bag does not work, since boss resists silencing...

**What characters and strategy could I use to beat the last boss?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out a way by using one of 'specially acquirable' characters Esther (If you don't have her sorry).

Characters: Esther and Diego essential, then Signy and some dps (Theo,...)

The setup before battle: Give Esther perk Synergistics so that she would AOE Energised

[image]

It's good if Signy has No stone unturned(5) also if Esther has Hollow-Point Blast(2) perks, but not essential.

Strategy:
0. Kill all the soldiers don't touch Carran he will parry, once they are down, move to 1-4
1. Get Esther to Energise Diego and Signy
2. Make energized Diego cast Target dummy next to Carran (no cooldown for energized).
3. When you have 2 authority points (also energized) Singy cast Massacre (~2k dmg)
4. On turns that target dummy is next to Carran Esther can shoot Penetration Round (~1k)

[image]
[image]

This way Carran should be deadlocked by Target dummy till he's dead. He will still be casting shield though, but you should have enough DPS...

Answer (score 0):

My take on this fight was different in where the damage comes from.

There are many strategies but 3 things to consider, pure damage bypass shield, there is a fish that destroy all the shield, poison bypass shield.

- Valen(with perk),Griffith, Signy, Theo - Pure
- Diego, Grenn - Poison